# Saving rom to have access from android recovery

Tags: android, rom

I'm using this code to update rom on android, the app placed in priv-apps and have `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in manifest

```
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh");
    OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
    os.write("echo 'boot-recovery ' > /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript".getBytes());
    os.write("echo '--update_package=/sdcard/0/update.zip' >> /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript".getBytes());
    os.write("echo '--wipe_cache' >> /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript".getBytes());
    os.write("echo 'reboot' >> /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript".getBytes());
    os.write("reboot recovery".getBytes());

    os.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
powerManager.reboot("recovery-update");
```

The phone doesn't have root and sdcard, where i need save through the app update.zip and update rom?

Comment: `/sdcard/` is an alias for the internal storage `/storage/emulated/0/`. It's not referring to an actual SD card.

Comment: @TheWanderer, thank you, i have edited my question! The main problem is how to flash without sdcard programarically